# What encompasses a function definition in C++?

Tags: c++, terminology

I think I'm getting conflicting information from cplusplus.com and MSDN on what exactly a "function definition" is in C++.

[MSDN seems to include the parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4d5ssht.aspx):

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

> The function can invoked, or called, from any number of places in the
>   program. The values that are passed to the function are the arguments,
>   whose types must be compatible with the **parameter types in the
>   function definition**.

Whereas [cplusplus does not](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/), implying the body (or is it the return expression/value?) of the function is its definition:

> Overloaded functions may have the same definition. For example:

```
int sum (int a, int b)
{
  return a+b;
}

double sum (double a, double b)
{
  return a+b;
}
```

Googling "function definition c++" gets a lot of definitions of what a function is, which I don't care about.

So, what components of a function make up its definition?

Comment: _"So, what components of a function make up its definition?"_ All of the parts, signature and body. make up the definition. You are probably confused vs. the term _declaration_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know defintion vs. declaration. I just don't get how cplusplus' example functions have the same definition. If parameter types are specific to a function's definition, are those not two different function definitions?

Comment: cplusplus is a bad and unreliable reference. I'd recommend en.cppreference.com

Comment: I think cplusplus is being sloppy here, and means that different overloads of a function can have the same body.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Fair enough. Is there a better introductory tutorial you'd recommend?

Comment: See what they have [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't agree about cplusplus.com. I have seem more mistakes on on.cppreference.com than I have at cplusplus.com. And cppreference.com is harder for novices  to understand imo.

Comment: @Galik: the difference is that cppreference.com is a wiki, and you could have fixed the mistakes you found (I do hope you did). It also has a much clearer overview of what exactly certain library functions do, which is often difficult to get at on cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's get some terminology straight:

- *function declaration*: also called the *function prototype*. It is the *function signature* and *name*, without the *function body*. Instead, it is followed by a semicolon.
- *function definition*: the *function declaration* (without semicolon) followed by a brace-enclosed block of code, called the *function body*.
- *function signature*: the return type and parameter types of a function. This is pretty much the *function prototype* excluding the *name*.
- *function body*: the actual code that will be executed, in the form of a brace-enclosed block of code.
- *function name*: the bit of the *function prototype* that is not the signature, or the semicolon. It is used to call the function.

Some examples:

```
// declaration/prototype
void  // return type
f     // function name
(int) // function parameter list
;     // semicolon
// definition
int g(double) // prototype part of the definition
{ return 42; } // the body, which really "defines" the function
// signature - in between the template's angle brackets < >
std::function<
              int(double)     // this bit is what one would call the signature
                         > h;
```

It is the *signature* that determines the function (pointer) type, and the signature+name that uniquely identifies a function when the linker starts linking everything together.

Why does cplusplus.com say that two functions can have the same definition? Well, that's wrong, at least in this example:

```
int sum(int a, int b)          { return a+b; }
double sum(double a, double b) { return a+b; }
```

Although the function bodies look the same, they express different underlying behaviour: in the integer case, the `+` signifies integer addition, in the latter case, it's floating point addition. These are two different (built-in) operators. All in all it's just a confusing example.